# Removing duplicates in grep output

Tags: bash, grep

I have a case where i got a results file with the following pattern:

```
path:pattern found
```

for example

```
./user/home/file1:this is a game
```

in other words when i searched for some string i got the file and the line it found it.

Problem is sometimes i have multiple cases in the same file so i would like to remove the duplicates files (the cases would be different so it's not possible).

Any help or ideas are appreciated :)

End results is to turn this:

```
/user/home/desktop/file1:this is a game
/user/home/desktop/file1:what kind of game
/user/home/desktop/file1:fast action game
```

into just the first results found without losing all the rest of the data in the file.

**Update1:**

So the actual file looks like this:

```
/user/home/desktop/file1:this is a game
/user/home/desktop/file1:what kind of game
/user/home/desktop/file1:fast action game
/user/home/desktop/file2:a game
/user/home/desktop/file3:of game
/user/home/desktop/file4:fast game
```

i'm looking to get rid of the multiple occurrences in the same file so it should look like this:

```
/user/home/desktop/file1:this is a game
/user/home/desktop/file2:a game
/user/home/desktop/file3:of game
/user/home/desktop/file4:fast game
```

Comment: What should be the final output for the example you have described?

Comment: Please update your question with that info.  Comments are not the best place for explaining your question.

Comment: Added an update to my question

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use `sort -u`:

```
grep pattern files | sort -t: -u -k1,1
```

- `-t:`   - use : as the delimiter
- `-k1,1` - sort based on the first field only
- `-u`    - removed duplicates (based on the first field)

This will retain just one occurrence of files, removing any duplicates.

For your example, this is the output you get:

```
/user/home/desktop/file1:this is a game
```

In case you are looking for multiple distinct matches with a file, then:

```
grep pattern files | sort -u
```

Comment: but that wont' give him the base path?

Comment: I'm not sure you got my problem right i have a results file specifying paths and the found strings, i'm looking to get rid of multiple instances in the same file and only keep one. problem is the lines are different apart from the path which is the same file they were found in. so how can i perform a unique command if it's not exactly the same? and if i cut the path and sort based on it i lose the actual results found so that too doesn't help...

Comment: I see codeforester answer is better. Didn't see clearly that result file already had the file with base path in it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the multiplicity switch in `grep`? This is an excerpt from the manpage:

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
   Stop  reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is standard input from a regular file, and
   NUM matching lines are output, grep ensures that the standard input is positioned  to  just  after  the
   last  matching line before exiting, regardless of the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables
   a calling process to resume a search.  When grep  stops  after  NUM  matching  lines,  it  outputs  any
   trailing  context  lines.   When  the  -c  or --count option is also used, grep does not output a count
   greater than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is also used, grep stops after  outputting  NUM
   non-matching lines.
```

So, using `grep -m 1 "pattern" files` you can limit the amount of results per file to one.

Answer (score 0):

In case raw file names are sufficient, one can use `grep pattern -l`, where `-l` option is documented as "print only names of FILEs with selected lines". But it turns out that each file is printed only once, even when multiple lines are matched inside.

The resulting output in your case would be:

```
/user/home/desktop/file2
/user/home/desktop/file3
/user/home/desktop/file4
```

Comment: But the OP clearly said they do not want path only.

Comment: I answered as this solution may be useful for other people getting here from i.e. Google (like me), as the question title is not specific. Anyway, in current form of the question the OP won't get line content for every but the first matched file line. So path seems to be the crux.